# \frac fails in tabular environment

Tags: tables, math-mode

Surprisingly the following code shown below fails if there's a `\frac`, if not it works fine i.e. x/y(z) etc

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} &\frac{3}{4}
\end{tabular}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: `tabular` starts text mode, thus you need math mode again to get `\frac` work: `$\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{3}{4}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabular` starts text mode, thus math mode needs to be set for the cells to get `\frac` work:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{3}{4}$\\
\end{tabular}
```

If it is used inside math mode, environment `array` can be used, which automatically switches the cells to math mode, see Mico's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305987/16967).

Another approach is offered by package `siunitx`, where different quotient forms can be configured with the same input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \sisetup{quotient-mode=fraction}
  \verb|\sisetup{quotient-mode=fraction}|:
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \num{1/2} & \num{3/4}\\
  \end{tabular}

  \sisetup{quotient-mode=symbol}
  \verb|\sisetup{quotient-mode=symbol}|:
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \num{1/2} & \num{3/4}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using an `array` environment, in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} & x/y(z) 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```